# How to convert --query return to string (az-devops cli with Powershell)

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-repos

I'm trying to assign a --query's returned id value into a variable as a string so that I can use the variable to input the id in other commands in Windows Powershell:

```
$repoID = az repos list --query "`"[?contains(name,'$Name')].id`""
az repos policy approver-count create --repository-id $repoID
```

but $repoID contains

```
[
"id value"
]
```

Would anyone know how to convert the return into a string so that $repoID = "id value" and becomes a valid parameter input?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use another output by setting `-o tsv`

```
$repoID = az repos list --query "`"[?contains(name,'$Name')].id`"" -o tsv
```